# code that's always executed before app gets visible?

Tags: ios8

I would like to secure an app of mine with a lockscreen. Currently, it's shown in `didBecomeActive`, but it seems as if that's a little bit too late as the content is visible for a short time sometimes before the lockscreen is shown.

As the lockscreen is not always shown (e.g. only if the app was suspended for more that 30 seconds), I don't want to add it in `applicationWillResignActive`.

One method would be to start a timer then and add the lockscreen after 30 seconds in the background, but I don't like that solution, I would prefer a method like `WILLbecomeActive`- is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: The natural thing would be to have the lockscreen be the initial scene in your storyboard.  Is there a reason that approach wouldn't work?

Comment: the lockscreen shouldn't be shown in some cases (the user disabled it, the user only tries the demo account, ...). Then I have the same problem in the other direction - the lockscreen is visible for a short time although it shouldn't, right?